# Git в IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Как сделать чтобы IDEA не запоминала мой email при коммите. Нужно чтобы при коммите она спрашивала email и пароль как делает это при первом коммите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

email пользователя запоминает не IDEA, a git. И хранит его в файле `.git/config`, нравится это вам или нет.

Самое простое, что вы можете сделать - повесить post-commit hook, который бы удалял ваш email из этого файла.

Кроме того, разумеется, вы можете взять исходники git-а, выпилить то, что вам мешает и пересобрать.

Comment: true linux way ))